# Unable to kill a process that shows up on ps aux

Tags: kill, zombie-process

[image]
I am unable to close WinZip. My command is shown below. Note that I don't think it is what is called a zombie program because according to [this website](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/how-kill-zombie-processes-linux), when I tried to find zombie program by typing PID 3010 does not show up.(see below)

[image]

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Answer (score 1):

According to your first `ps` output you are **not** running WinZip. What you see and trying to kill is `ps` itself. Maybe you should run `grep` with `-i`.

**Edit**: That's indeed the case.

Try `kill -9 401` or even better `pkill -9 WinZip`.

According to the `stat` column WinZip is very much alive and sleeping - it is *not* a zombie process (which is indicated by the letter `Z`).

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for yout timely reply. Would you help me out here, I thought "ps aux | grep winzip" should return all process run by winzip?

Comment: grep is **case sensitive** by default that's why your first command didn't work and this one won't work as well. Again, as I've already told, please use `-i`, i.e. `grep -i winzip`.